# Which LINQ expression is better?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, search

I was wondering which of the following LINQ expressions is better (especially in terms of performance).

Notes:

- length of **SearchKeywords** is usually around 50
- length of **keywords** is usually around 3
- this method is called around 100,000 times

this one?

```
keywords.All(a => SearchKeywords.Contains(a));
```

or this one

```
keywords.Except(SearchKeywords).None();
```

Note: .None() is my extension method which simply returns !.Any()

Is there any better way to write this?

Regards

Comment: Well, what do your performance measurements say?

Comment: you should add AsParallel Here.

Comment: I suppose parallel for 3 items is neutral

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Except` will be approximately a gazillion times faster because it uses a hashtable to find the set difference¹ and thus will give O(n) performance.

The `Contains`/`All` combo would have to do a naive linear search² over `SearchKeywords` for each element in `keywords`, so we are talking O(n²) performance (actually `n * m`, but the numbers you give are in the same range and take any excuse I can to type exponents).

**Update:** as expected, [it's not even close](http://www.ideone.com/4PTsH) unless you explicitly create a `HashSet`.

---

¹Unless of course `SearchKeywords` *already is* a `HashSet<string>`, as flq very rightly points out in a comment.

²At least if we 're talking about an `IEnumerable`, which uses the LINQ to objects standard implementation. An `IQueryable` could theoretically detect this and implement it any way it likes.

Comment: unless SearchKeywords *is* a HashSet, which I suppose Except would first have to construct.

Comment: @flq: Very true. I updated the answer and the benchmark to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I think

```
keywords.Except(SearchKeywords).None();
```

is faster than previous one because it may require to scan throught once for the collection of SearchKeywork.

Answer (score 0):

The first option is far more readable and is compatible with LINQ to SQL if SearchWords is a local collection

The second option is not compatible with Linq To SQL.

Comment: You can even rewrite the first one as `Keywords.All(SearchWords.Contains)`